# Java version of HttpWebRequest seDefaultCredentials = true;

Tags: java, c#, apache-httpclient-4.x, qliksense

I am currently working on authorizing the Qlik API proxy using Java. To do this I have to navigate through several redirects and then open a WebSocket. I have a version of C# that completes the task but need to port it over to java.

In Java, I am able to complete the redirects and obtain the session key for the WebSocket but I cannot seem to configure the NTLM credentials correctly for the WebSocket to accept them.

I am currently using apache HTTP client v 4.5. And nv-websocket-client for the WebSocket.

https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/index.html

https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client

In Java, I made a credentials object and set the NTLM credentials for the https request.

The issue is that in C# the call to the WebSocket seems to be automatically picking up the request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;.

My question is there a way to get this same functionality in Java or a library that supports the functions. Or if someone has used Java to complete this task any insight would be great.

I have tried configuring the headers for the WebSocket request to mirror the NTLM request, but I am not really sure where to go from here. Below is the c# set up I am looking to complete the same task.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(URI);  
request.Headers = headers;  
        request.Method = "GET";  
        request.Accept = "application/json";  
        request.Credentials = true;    
System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;  
        request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;  
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;  
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
```

I am currently receiving:

> webSocketFrame(FIN=1,RSV1=0,RSV2=0,RSV3=0,Opcode=TEXT,Length=226,Payload="
>
> {"jsonrpc":"2.0",
>      "method":"OnAuthenticationInformation",
>      "params":{"loginUri":baseurl+port"/internal_windows_authentication/?
>      targetId=ID returned here",
>      "mustAuthenticate":true}}")

The response I am looking for it:

> webSocketFrame(FIN=1,RSV1=0,RSV2=0,RSV3=0,Opcode=TEXT,Length=226,Payload="
>       {"jsonrpc":"2.0",
>       "method":"OnAuthenticationInformation",
>       "params":{"loginUri":baseurl+port"/internal_windows_authentication/? 
>       targetId=ID returned here ",
>       "mustAuthenticate":false}}") <---- the boolean flag is changed

Comment: Do you find a solution @luke